# iTextSharp: What is Lost When Copying PDF Content From Another PDF?

Tags: pdf, itext

I am currently evaluating iTextSharp for potential use in a project. The code that I have written to achieve my goal is making use of PDFCopy.GetImportedPage to copy all of the pages from an existing PDF. What I want to know is what all do I need to be aware of that will be lost from a PDF and/or page when duplicating PDF content like this? For example, one thing that I already noticed is that I need to manually add in any bookmarks and named destinations into my new PDF.

Here's some rough sample code:

```
        using (PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(inputFilename))
        {
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (Document document = new Document())
                {
                    using (PdfCopy copy = new PdfCopy(document, ms))
                    {
                        document.Open();

                        int n;
                        n = reader.NumberOfPages;
                        for (int page = 0; page < n; )
                        {
                            copy.AddPage(copy.GetImportedPage(reader, ++page));
                        }

                        // add content and make further modifications here
                    }
                }

                // write the content to disk
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically anything that's document-level instead of page-level will get lost and both Bookmarks and Destinations are document-level. Pull up the [PDF spec](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_reference_1-7.pdf) and look at section 3.6.1 for other entries in the document catalog including Threads, Open and Additional Actions and Meta Data.

You might already have seen these but here are some samples (in Java) of how to [merge Named Destinations](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=133) and how to [merge Bookmarks](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=141).